# WPF: Changing the look of a Surface Listbox "click-effect"

Tags: wpf, listbox, pixelsense

I'm changing the look of some Controls that I use in my Microsoft Surface Application at the moment. And today I'm working on a SurfaceListBox.

I have the template for it and already changed background and borders and other stuff.
But I really cannot find where I can change the color of the rectangle that appears on the ListBoxItem when you touch the ListBox. At the moment it's just white and I want to change that.

It's not something like the effect that you can see when the item is selected. I already found that and changed that so my selected item now appears in a different color. But the effect in the second when you touch the item stays white.

So where can I change this effect?

Comment: I still haven't found it =( Anybody there who can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the bright, white highlight that happens when you press your finger against an item you should look into the [SurfaceShadowChrome](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.generic.surfaceshadowchrome.aspx). It's used by (almost) all surface controls to give feedback when the user is pressing on a control.

It does have a [Color](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.surface.presentation.generic.surfaceshadowchrome.color.aspx) property that you can modify to suit your needs. Apart from the color, and the tweaking of corner radius and shadow offset, it's not a very flexible decorator. But hopefully, you'll be able to make it do what you need.

Comment: Oh thank you very much. Now I know what I have to look for =)

Comment: This looks nice. Do you know how the resources is named? "shadow"?

Comment: No, can't remember of the top of my head. But if you scan the template for instances of `SurfaceShadowChrome` it should be fairly obvious which it is (you may need to change more than one, since triggers may be used to switch between templates inside the style)